# Control network in cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, networking

I need to implent a control in my app. If there's no wireless network where I can connect, i need to create an ad-hoc network. It's possible to do it in obj-c with cocoa? I can't find anything about that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing. So far all I've found is apple scripts and using automator to accomplish the same thing - but there must be something out there.